# Bootstrap dropdown menu items missing style

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I do a search for the class "dropdown-item", I get no results even in the bootstrap.css or .js. Where is this class?

Here's what I get:

[image]

With the following code:

```
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Action
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I also have my scripts in the correct order:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

All my other controls (navbar, buttons, button groups, etc.) are working well so bootstrap seems to be correctly initialized.

Comment: Have you attached `bootstrap.css` as well?

Comment: Add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">` in your head.

Comment: I do have also the css to bootstrap, sorry

Comment: Are you sure the css is in the Content folder? Normally its in the css folder.

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a container div with class `"dropdown"`, here's the example from bootstrap website:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a `dropdown` class on the wrapper div that you're missing.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks...I was looking at v4 alpha bootstrap page for my reference >_< ....no container required there it seems

Answer (score 5):

You need to utilize `ul` and `li` elements in your dropdown. See your working [CODE HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/ALRZLR) and below.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
             <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
             <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
             <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
             <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need that `<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>` anymore